# How can i use malayalam ASCII fonts?

Tags: android

I am a beginner in app developers.I am facing a problem while adding ASCII fonts in Text View.How can i add some text in the text box which are in ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approach that you can use

**1) If data is contains HTML along with ASCII.**

```
 txtview.setText(Html.fromHtml(asciiString));
```

**2) If data is contains only ASCII.**

```
try {
        textView.setText(new String(asciiString.getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Example:**

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        try {
            textView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "APPLET.TTF"));
            textView.setText(new String("bYmÀ° AÀlXbpÅh³".getBytes("UTF-8"),"UTF-8"));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Outout:**

[image]

**NOTE:**

Put **APPLET.TTF** file in assets folder of your project

Comment: i am a beginner... so i do't know where i put this..!!

Comment: post your code that you did so that I can assist you

Comment: Actually what i want to do is that.. i have a word document, it is in a  ASCII font format, i just want to copy this data into the text view.

Comment: where is word doc on sdcard? or in asset folder

Comment: copy the file and paste in asset folder

Comment: can i mail a sample page to u... can u help me..?

Comment: yes you can mail it to me get my mail id from profile

Comment: ho god... im so soryy, u need to put another font for view dat. i w'll forwd

Comment: did u get that..?? it iz a malayalam word means "Realy deserve person"

Comment: For the same.. how can i get 1 or two paragraph instead of that word..??

Answer (score 1):

Switch your text encoding to `UTF-8`.

In Eclipse go to `Window -> Preferences, select General -> Workspace.` From the Text file encoding dropdown, select UTF-8.

do as follows:

download AnjaliOldLipi.ttf font.that's the malayalam font .search google for the file. under your android assets folder create if not exist the folder fonts: `assets/fonts/AnjaliOldLipi.ttf`

then display texts this way were textview is a TextView: `textview.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/AnjaliOldLipi.ttf")`)